# Blocking URLs and canonical questions

Tags: seo, robots.txt, canonical-url

We are running a Magento store set up and was looking to block all pages with the exception of a select few.

It seems the only way we can do this is with blocking direct paths to files that are in the root and then wildcarding various other diretories.

My question is if we have a product like website/ultragloss-black.html the canonical is actually /zurfiz/ultragloss-solid-colours/ultragloss-black.html

If we block /zurfiz/* will this block the short url version as the canonical is in the /zurfiz/ directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't block the short url version, but it does mean that you're telling search engines "the canonical is here but I don't want you to look at it", which defeats the object of having a canonical page.

Comment: ok, another quick related question... if I was to block /ultragloss-black.html would that block every instance of it or just the one in the root?

Comment: Just the one in the root.